# JS: dynamically populate/combine object with nested objects/properties > do we have a simpler way?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, properties, populate

The problem: I've a JS global var that I've to check if it as an object with "menus configurations" and populate with the missing configurations.

So this work is based on this AS2:

```
        var result_array = re.result.items;

        _global.menu_array = new Array();
        var menu_type_num:Number = -1;
        var menu_group_num:Number = -1;
        var menu_id_num:Number = -1;
        for (var i=0; i<result_array.length; i++){
            if (menu_type_num != result_array[i].menu_type){
                menu_type_num = result_array[i].menu_type;
                menu_group_num = -1;
                var type_array:Array = new Array();
                _global.menu_array[menu_type_num] = type_array;
            }
            if (menu_group_num != result_array[i].menu_group){
                menu_group_num = result_array[i].menu_group;
                var group_array:Array = new Array();
                _global.menu_array[menu_type_num][menu_group_num] = group_array;
            }
            var menu_obj:Object = new Object();
            menu_id_num = menu_obj.menu_id = Number(result_array[i].menu_id);
            menu_obj.menu_text = result_array[i].menu_text;
            _global.menu_array[menu_type_num][menu_group_num][menu_id_num] = menu_obj;
        }
```

I've reached to this solution in JS:

```
result.then(function(res)
    {
        if(!_MEV2_GLOBAL.hasOwnProperty("menu_array"))
        {
            _MEV2_GLOBAL.menu_array = {};
        }

        res.forEach(r =>
        {
            if(!_MEV2_GLOBAL.menu_array.hasOwnProperty(r.menu_type))
            {
                _MEV2_GLOBAL.menu_array[r.menu_type] = {};
            }


      if(!_MEV2_GLOBAL.menu_array[r.menu_type].hasOwnProperty(r.menu_group))
            {
                _MEV2_GLOBAL.menu_array[r.menu_type][r.menu_group] = {};
            }

            if(!_MEV2_GLOBAL.menu_array[r.menu_type][r.menu_group].hasOwnProperty(r.menu_id))
            {
                _MEV2_GLOBAL.menu_array[r.menu_type][r.menu_group][r.menu_id] = {
                    menu_id:   r.menu_id,
                    menu_text: r.menu_text
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

This works but doing an if for every sublevel... Do I have another way, something with reduce or whatever, more effective and concise?

I know a little about JS but I'm afraid my solution isn't the best aproach. Or am I falling to the "root of all evil" :P

**EDIT:**
The input comes from an IndexedDB "table", so the result is made of objects ("lines") similar to the one on the picture:
[for example, "t_menus_gre" *select* is the input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fR9t0.png)

This resultSet must be inserted on a GlobalVar, that should follow this structure:
[this object is my GlobalVar and should include a subObject['menu_array'] with menus configs by type/group/id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SCxr.png)

Comment: Could you give us an example input and expected output, please?

Comment: I've updated my question, I hope it was what you're asking ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... I honestly don't think I understood the logic behind that menu configuration, but based solely on your code I could make the following improvements:

```
result.then(res => {

    _MEV2_GLOBAL.menu_array = _MEV2_GLOBAL.menu_array || {};
    const array = _MEV2_GLOBAL.menu_array;

    res.forEach(r => {
        array[r.menu_type] = array[r.menu_type] || {};
        array[r.menu_type][r.menu_group] = array[r.menu_type][r.menu_group] || {};
        array[r.menu_type][r.menu_group][r.menu_id] = array[r.menu_type][r.menu_group][r.menu_id] || { menu_id: r.menu_id, menu_text: r.menu_text };
    });

});
```

If you just want to verify if a value is defined, javascript always evaluates `null`, `undefined`, `false`, `""` and `0` as **`false`**.

That way, when you execute `array[r.menu_type] = array[r.menu_type] || {};`, if `array[r.menu_type]` is undefined, it receives `{}`.

Hope  that helps you in some way.

Comment: It's from an old flash game (with no documentation at all) and I've to convert it to html5/JS, in record time... This have was online and now it's supposed to be almost completely offline. I'm maintaining the old logic, and this configurations are used on the canvas (old flash converted) by animateCC.

Comment: Hmmm, ok! Have you tried the code I wrote? :) @rantunes

Comment: It still works as supposed and is much more cleaner. Thanks for your advice, I didn't know I could do this kind of "ternary atributions"!